# Is there how I could programmatically ask eclipselink to drop and create all tables?

Tags: unit-testing, jdbc, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

This helps in unit testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
ServerSession session = entityManager.unwrap(ServerSession.class);  
SchemaManager schemaManager = new SchemaManager(session);  
schemaManager.replaceDefaultTables(true, true);
```

Comment: I've replaced your code with my database destroying code, but then tests fail. Why could that be? Do I have to run this code inside a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to execute the sql scripts eclipselink generates specifying:

```
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
```

in persistence.xml