# Debugging Cyc Server locally

Tags: opencyc

I got Cyc(ReserchCyc) instance installed locally.
Looking at the contents, I can see multiple war files for cyc(the version we are using).
So essentially cyc-enterprise is a web server hosting multiple wars(each war serving one purpose).

Here is the question:
I know we can always debug a web application via IDE (w/o source code just the class file)...have done this for a simple web-app with single war.

Can we setup local environment where we can debug the server(the component responsible for receiving the request and finally getting the answers…we won’t need source code for this..even class file should suffice)...any document/steps would be great.

Answer (score 1):

So to re-iterate, Cyc is written in a language named SubL and a formal Logic named CycL. To run on a real computer, these languages are re-written/compiled into the Java run-time system.  Cycorp has not volunteered if this is a source-code to source-code conversion or that SubL and CycL are converted in JVM (Java Virtual Machine) opcodes.

Any time you have Java code, you can convert it into JVM opcodes. These JVM opcodes,  are usually stored in files with the extension ".class" instead of being stored as Java Source code in files with the extension ".java"

Since class files usually need other class files to work better, they many times are stored in zip files, with a particular directory structure. Many times these zip files are treated as if they weren't compressed into one file.
To do this, you rename the zip files with a ".jar" extension (because they are Java ARchives) or a ".war" extension (for Web ARchive)

Since all programs have problems, and don't work the way they are intended, most languages have debugging environments that help you control the various pieces and figure out how they work and how to make them do what they are supposed to do.

Apparently, someone else has asked a similar question [Best way to debug Java web application packaged as a WAR using Eclipse and Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723743/best-way-to-debug-java-web-application-packaged-as-a-war-using-eclipse-and-maven)

What is not clear is if this method will work with the WAR files that you have available to you. Since you are the licensee of ResearchCyc, I expect you will have to try this yourself and tell us if these tools do what you need.

If we have not signed an agreement with Cycorp, we can't actually test them for you, and you can't make them available to outside parties (non-ResearchCyclists)
to let them try.